# How to use the MONTH() function from SPARQL to extract the month of a date in rdf4j?

Tags: sparql, rdf4j

How do I replicate the following filter from SPARQL in java using rd4j?

```
FILTER(?endDate > NOW() && ?startDate < NOW() && MONTH(?endDate) = MONTH(NOW()))
```

I have initialised expressions for `MONTH()` and `NOW()` as follows, and a graph pattern `pattern`, but don't know how to use them to extract the month from variable `?endDate` and from the `NOW()` function

```
    Expression<?> nowFunc = Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.NOW );
    Expression<?> month = Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.MONTH);
    
    Expression<?> endDateGreaterThan = Expressions.gt(endDate, nowFunc);
    Expression<?> startDateLessThan = Expressions.lt(startDate, nowFunc);
```

The query I have so far is as follows, but I can't figure out how to implement the final part (****) of the filter into the query.

```
SelectQuery query = Queries.SELECT().prefix(ex).select(letter).where(pattern.filter(Expressions.
and(endDateGreaterThan, startDateLessThan, ****)
```

Comment: the signature is `Expressions.function(SparqlFunction function, Operand... operands)`, so you should provide the variable resp. the expression of `NOW()` as an operand of your `MONTH` expression

Comment: Question was also asked (and answered) on RDF4J user list: https://groups.google.com/g/rdf4j-users/c/0b_2wQfMWkQ/m/C0MdQreLBwAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no different from how you have set up your other expressions. You want an equals comparison operation between two value expressions (let's call them `leftArg` and `rightArg`), so:

```java
Expression monthEquals = Expressions.equals(leftArg, rightArg);
```

Your `leftArg` and `rightArg` are both also functions, both with a single operand. The `leftArg` has a simple variable as its function operand:

```java
Expression leftArg = Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.MONTH, endDate);
```

The `rightArg` has a `NOW()` function as its operand:

```java
Expression rightArg = Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.MONTH,
        Expressions.function(SparqlFunction.NOW));
```

Just put it all together and you're done.